# How To Save Changes made To The Items of A list

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

My app displays a customed list of videos with the option to download using IntentService. The custom list is displayed on the UI using a recyclerView system. Below is a pic of the list

[image]

When a video is clicked and downloaded, the download icon turns blue as seen in the first child of the list shown in the picture above and when it has not been downloaded it shows the default black download icon. I have strung up some codes to make it work, the challenge is, when the app is restarted, The download icon revert to its default color even when it was previously downloaded. How do I update and save changes made to the color of the download icon so it will reflect when the app is restarted? I understand the SharedPreference class can be used to save changes made to the App, but I don't know how to achieve this. Would appreciate any assist that can be lent to achieve this

Below is my onCreate mtd

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lecture);
    setUpRecyclerView();
```

And below is where I created the setUpRecyclerView()

```
 private void setUpRecyclerView() {
    Query query = lectureRef.orderBy("position", Query.Direction.ASCENDING);
    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<LectureClasses> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<LectureClasses>()
            .setQuery(query, LectureClasses.class).build();
    adapter = new LectureClassesAdapter(options);
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Below is my call of the onViewItemclick @overide method setup in my adapter class

```
 @Override
public void onViewItemClick(DocumentSnapshot snapshot, int position, View itemView) {
    //init variables
    CircularProgressBar progressBarCir = itemView.findViewById(R.id.progress_circular);
    progressBarCir.setProgressMax(100f);
    ImageView downloadImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.download);
    PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(LectureActivity.this,downloadImage);
    LectureClasses lectureClasses = snapshot.toObject(LectureClasses.class);
    lectureClasses = adapter.getItem(position);
    String titleNow = lectureClasses.getTitle();
    String urlNow = lectureClasses.getUrl();

     class DownloadReceiver extends ResultReceiver { 

        public DownloadReceiver(Handler handler) {
            super(handler);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
            super.onReceiveResult(resultCode, resultData);
            if (resultCode == TichaDownloadService.UPDATE_PROGRESS) {
                int progress = resultData.getInt("progress"); 
                progressBarCir.setProgress(progress);
                downloadImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                progressBarCir.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Log.i("STATUS","DOWNLOADING>>>");
                if (progress == 100) {
                   progressBarCir.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                   downloadImage.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.download_blue));
                   downloadImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }else  {
                Log.i("STATUS"," NOT DOWNLOADING,BOSS");
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Where do you save the files(video) ??

Comment: @Javad Dehban, On the external memory of the device. not SD

Comment: To what address file?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you,@Javad Dehban, but if you are referring to the location uri, it looks like this  `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString()+videoFile;`

Answer (score 0):

you are can to check the file with below code

```
 File videoFile = new File("patch_video_file");
    if (videoFile.exists()){
        // visible button blue
    }else {
        // visible button default
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, @Javad Dehban, but checking for file existence is really not the challenge here, but how to access the List items in the onCreate method. The only way I know to access the listView items is the `@Overide ` of onViewItemClick and it only works with a click of the items. If after checking for the existence of the file, how do I access the download icon? I can only change it appearing if I have access

Comment: How is this inserted?(list)

Comment: the list is inserted on the UI by calling  setUpRecyclerView(); in the `onCreate` but the children are accessed by onItemViewClick override. as seen in my code above

Comment: You can add a parameter to your list as an (IsExist). false by default.
Then when the download is done, true that amount

Comment: Always check this parameter when running the app

Comment: I said before that checking for file existence is not the challenge, that’s an easy thing to do. I feel a second look at the question and the code will give better insight to the question . The challenge is rather, how to update and save changes made to the customed list drawable so it can be persistent. Think about it, there are good number of videos on the  list, it wouldn’t be realistic to check if each video has been downloaded.

Comment: Maybe, you can tell me where to check (isExist) to update the drawable. If I figure that out, it might help.